# add a dash to a specific digits entered by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I did find this function in jQuery that add a dash after very four numbers, but I would like to add a dash to a number entered by the user with the follow format:

1234-1234556-123-1

but I could manage to get it, could you please help me, this is the jQuery function that formats the follow: 1234-1234-1234-1

```
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if ((foo.length > 0) && (foo.length < 14)) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

Comment: I'm little confused. In which format user is entered data and to which format you want to format it.

Comment: the user enters 12345678901234 just numbers and the output desired format is 1234-567890-123-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parenthetical matching groups.  Put the pattern in parenthesis.  This will return an array with the whole match, followed by the parenthetical matches, followed by some match info.  So, you have to slice out array elements 1-4, and then join them with dashes.  Because some of the matches may be empty, you can clean up with another replace that removes trailing dashes:

**Edit**:  You could also remove all non-numeric characters, instead of just hyphens.  (See second line)

```
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ""); // remove non-numerics
  if ((foo.length > 0) && (foo.length < 16)) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('(\\d{1,4})(\\d{0,7})(\\d{0,3})(\\d?)')).slice(1,5).join("-").replace(/\-+$/, '');
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/oohfksjd/

Comment: The correct regex is `(\d{1,4})(\d{0,6})(\d{0,3})(\d?)`

Comment: The OP has 7 digits in the second group, so I went with that.  The principle is the same though.

Answer (score -1):

It is more RegExp issue, not JavaScript.

```
RegExp('(.{1,4})(.{1,7})(.{1,3})(.{1,1})', 'g')
```

Comment: Thanks, I just add the RexExp you exposed but now it doesn´t add the dash

Comment: You don't need the `(g)lobal` flag if you are simply matching a line, `.{1,1}` should simply be `.`  and actually `.` means "any character" so using `\d` is more preferable/efficient

Comment: @kuzyn I totaly agree, it is not very clean expression. Placed this to show the OP a hint, and got stuck on removing the 'whole match' part - the first array element, which obvoiusly can be done with slice()